# Upload Flat file from Local Directory to Azure File Shares

Tags: azure, ssis

I am looking for a way to upload a flat file to file.core.windows.net in Azure Storage. Uploading to a Blob storage is easy enough and straight forward using SSIS's Azure Blob Upload task, however I need the file to go to the File shares not the blob containers. I have tried to use AZCopy however I cannot seem to get it to work, so I was curious if anyone knew of an easier way to upload to the File Shares? I have access to the account name and Storage key for the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using AZCopy, I realized the instructions i received was from an older version of AZCopy with different keywords (Version 8 instead of the newest V10)